# Trying to extract Commit logs for GNU Octave software

Tags: logging, octave, commit, gnu

I want to work on the commit history of GNU Octave. I downloaded the source code from https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/. But I am not sure of the location to extract the commit logs of the project. Where can I download it?

Comment: use mercurial/hg (of course not on the source tarball but the repo) or browse http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave

Comment: but i am unable to donwload it

Comment: "It doesn't work" or "I am unable to.." should include the problem you've encountered

Comment: if you go to the link you have provided it shows all the commits, i wanted to download the whole commit log from first commit, there is no option of downloading that data which is shown in that link

Comment: And what was the other thing I've suggested?

Comment: Can you explain me how to use mercurial/hg to download the commit logs?

Answer (score 0):

Make a local clone of the repo using Mercurial and then run `hg log` to get the full history.

```
hg clone https://www.octave.org/hg/octave
cd octave
hg log
```

If you want to see it in forward chronological order:

```
hg log -r :
```

Comment: I have tried the commands which you have mentioned then it returned the following error:

Comment: transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: HTTP request error (incomplete response; expected 3046 bytes got 5146) (in subrepository "gnulib")
hint: this may be an intermittent network failure; if the error persists, consider contacting the network or server operator
[command returned code 255 Wed May 15 08:06:11 2019]

Comment: Yeah, that gnulib subrepository is pesky; it throws errors like this every now and then. Just try it again, and if the problem is still happening, send an email reporting it to the help-octave@gnu.org mailing list and they'll get it straightened out.